# PostgreSQL Database entering recovery mode

Tags: postgresql

We noticed that our database sometimes goes into recovery mode.

And looking at the Ubuntu logs we found this information.

```
postgres-01 kernel: [xxxx.xxx] postgres[xxxx]: segfault at xxxxxx ip XXXX sp XXXX 8 error 6 in libc.so.6 (deleted)[xxxx+xxx] likely on CPU 2 (core 2, socket)
```

Could there be an application that is deleting this library or even standalone updates that remove it during update?

- Version 14.10
- Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: segfault is usually because of a bug

Comment: Get the core dump and [generate a stack trace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD). Add that to the question.